# requests - how to stream upload - partial file

Tags: python, python-requests

My goal is to do a PUT of part of a file using requests and stream the file (i.e., not load it into memory and then do the PUT).

[This page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads) explains how you would do that for an entire file:

> Requests supports streaming uploads, which allow you to send large
>   streams or files without reading them into memory. To stream and
>   upload, simply provide a file-like object for your body:

```
with open('massive-body', 'rb') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/streamed', data=f)
```

However in my case I want to only send one chunk of the file.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

In concept, something like:

```
with open('massive-body', 'rb') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/streamed', data=f.read(chunksize))
```

Comment: hmm, you could probably write a generator pretending to be a file-like object that will read a chunk behind the scenes, may be tricky though as I'm not sure what calls requests do on a file, but seems possible if none comes up with better solution

Comment: @user3012759: I tried searching for what Request requires in a file-like object, to no avail. However, note that it accepts a simple generator for [Chunk-Encoded Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests)

Comment: I guess you could experiment using a basic file-like class that has `read` and `close` methods, and if that doesn't work keep adding methods to your class until Requests stops complaining. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring chunk-encoded should work as well imho, with the right headers set it should be rally easy to craft a generator to send part of a file in chunks

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "My goal is to do a PUT of part of a file using requests and stream the file". Do you also not want to read that *chunk* into memory? If that's what you want, I can help you come up with a solution. For your information, if reading the chunk into memory is okay, then your second snippet will work just fine.

Comment: @sigmavirus24, that's right I don't want to load all of 'f.read(chunksize)' into memory.

Comment: Would a version of Joe's code (modified as per my comment) that can be used to do chunk-encoded requests be acceptable? Or would you prefer to use a custom file-like class so that you can take advantage of Request's streaming support?

Answer (score 11):

Based off Greg's answers to my questions I think the following will work best:

First you'll need something to wrap your open file so that it limits how much data can be read:

```
class FileLimiter(object):
    def __init__(self, file_obj, read_limit):
        self.read_limit = read_limit
        self.amount_seen = 0
        self.file_obj = file_obj

        # So that requests doesn't try to chunk the upload but will instead stream it:
        self.len = read_limit

    def read(self, amount=-1):
        if self.amount_seen >= self.read_limit:
            return b''
        remaining_amount = self.read_limit - self.amount_seen
        data = self.file_obj.read(min(amount, remaining_amount))
        self.amount_seen += len(data)
        return data
```

This should roughly work as a good wrapper object. Then you would use it like so:

```
 with open('my_large_file', 'rb') as file_obj:
     file_obj.seek(my_offset)
     upload = FileLimiter(file_obj, my_chunk_limit)
     r = requests.post(url, data=upload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

The headers are obviously optional, but when streaming data to a server, it's a good idea to be a considerate user and tell the server what the type of the content is that you're sending.

Comment: thanks, this is just what i needed!

one minor bug fix to `read` for when `amount` is -1:
`data = self.file_obj.read(remaining_amount if amount < 0 else min(amount, remaining_amount))`

Comment: How can we send the filename to the server with this method?

Comment: What is the "chucksize" itself is big and this is in multithreading. I think  calling read() will cause memoryIssue ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm just throwing 2 other answers together so bear with me if it doesn't work out of the box—I have no means of testing this:

[Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests

```py
def read_in_chunks(file_object, blocksize=1024, chunks=-1):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while chunks:
        data = file_object.read(blocksize)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
        chunks -= 1


requests.post('http://some.url/chunked', data=read_in_chunks(f))
```

Comment: Note that Greg does **not** want to upload the whole file. Maybe you should change your `chunk_size` to something else, eg `blocksize`, since Greg is using `chunksize` to mean the total size of the data to be transferred. FWIW, your code can be easily modified to break out of the loop when `chunksize` bytes have been sent, the only trick is that the last block may be short if `chunksize % blocksize` isn't zero.

Comment: I updated the example so you can specify a maximum number of chunks

Comment: Ok. That works. The caller has to ensure that `blocksize` is a divisor of `chunksize`, but hopefully that's not a major issue.

Comment: This looks promising!  So if I also wanted to start at a certain offset in the large file, I could just throw a seek in there before the while statement?

Comment: So if I'm ok with the last block being short, I don't have to worry about ensuring that blocksize is a divisor of chunksize?

Comment: file_object.read() states that it will read "at most" blocksize, and will not complain if there isn't enough bytes, so you should be in the clear: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

Comment: It did not work for me, I got a strange exception from requests ('HTTPSConnectionPool' object has no attribute 'getresponse'). Since the FileLimiter solution works for me I did not investigate any further.