# How to upload file by PUT on python without opening the file

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, pycurl

Problem:

1) Need a python library which accepts path of file instead of opening the file(as it can be huge) to make a PUT request.
2) Also want that library to automatically do the redirect if exists(Requests library does that)

The shell command for this is `curl -T`

I've tried requests, it does redirect but needs to open file to send the file. Same is the case for pyCurl. The only alternative left is running a shell command in the python code.

Comment: When you say open the file, you mean open and read all of its contents into memory, right? Perhaps this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775247/requests-how-to-stream-upload-partial-file

Comment: The pycurl example [file_upload.py](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/examples/file_upload.py) does an upload in a streaming manner. Similar to `curl -T`.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I didnt want to open the file, instead just want to give the file path and make a request, like `curl -T` which takes only the path

Comment: @DanielStenberg I can see, `open(filename, 'rb')` in the url u have given. Wanted to avoid that

Comment: even `curl -T` to send file it has to open it and read it to send data to socket/connection but you don't see this. Computers can't send file without opening it and reading it to memory (whole or piece by piece)

Comment: You *can't* avoid opening the file if you want to get to the contents of it. You want to avoid loading the entire contents into memory first and *then* sending it but you can't avoid opening it.

Comment: @furas Didn't knew that. Thank you. Let me know if i have to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

In pycurl, both READDATA and READFUNCTION should stream the data from the open file. As pointed out in the comments, opening the file is required to do anything with its contents.

In general you can verify that your program is streaming data rather than reading the file in memory by monitoring its memory usage while it is executing and providing it with a large input file (e.g. > 100 MB).